# Selenium simple Click operation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium IDE, the operation is :

```
"Click" locator: "//*[@panel-id='3']"
```

Then I transform code to Java I get:

```
Selenium selenium;
selenium.click("//*[@panel-id='3']");
```

As result i get exception " Element is not currently visible "

```
selenium.isVisible("//*[@panel-id='3']");
```

respond exception too;

Where is problem?

Comment: so does the element exist in HTML? can you show?

Comment: @eis <div class="Zvc HAd SSd I9" data-tooltip="Расскажите, где вы жили" aria-label="Расскажите, где вы жили" tabindex="0" role="button" panel-id="3"

Comment: that says `panel-id="3"` you are looking for `panel-id="2"`

Comment: @sircapsalot I've corrected id

Comment: Well what element is it? Does it become visible & "enabled" when a user does something? Is it a case of waiting for the page to load? Is that element even there on a page load?

Comment: I just used another way to search the button

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Selenium selenium;
selenium.click("//*[@id='3']");
```